# Custom object with nested collection

Tags: c#

I've created an object that contains another collection in one of it properties.

This is the main object:

```
public class MeterPrevReadInfo
{
    public int JobMeterID { get; set; }
    public string PreviousJobReference { get; set; }
    public FuelType MeterFuelType { get; set; }
    public List<MeterPrevReadRegInfo> Regs { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateMeterRead { get; set; }
}
```

This is the child object:

```
public class MeterPrevReadRegInfo
{
    public string RegisterID { get; set; }
    public string MeterRead { get; set; }
}
```

I need to bind this object to a repeater control, I would like to show the *DateMeterRead* property and all the *MeterRead* properties in the repeater.

Is this possible using Linq? I could easily do it using a t-sql query from the database, but I just figured it should be possible to do this in memory without the overhead of another trip to the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sure this is possible. It looks like you want something like this:

```
 List<MeterPrevReadInfo> list = ...;

 var result = from item in list
              from info in item.Regs
              select new {item.DateMeterRead, info.MeterRead};
```

This query defines a list of anonymous objects with the two properties you want.

Answer (score 1):

Don't get confused - LINQ isn't a data access layer or ORM (perhaps you're thinking of LINQ-to-SQL, or LINQ-to-Entities?)

You can absolutely query an in-memory collection using LINQ, although your questions seems to relate to database.

> I could easily do it using a t-sql
>   query from the database, but I just
>   figured it should be possible to do
>   this in memory without the overhead of
>   another trip to the database.

You can retrieve all this data from the database in one query & then construct objects. You can do this with a stored procedure, LINQ-to-SQL, Entity Framework, or other tools. You should choose the best tool for your requirements. I expect this is a very small part of the requirement, so take a step back, choose the best tool, and make this work using that tool.

Answer (score 0):

You can access an anonymous object representing the model you want by using the Linq `Select` extension method as follows:

```
var readInfo = new MeterPrevReadInfo();
readInfo.Regs.Select(x => new {
                                        x.RegisterID, 
                                        x.MeterRead, 
                                        readInfo.DateMeterRead
                                       });
```